# Laravel display withCount() query results in groups

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have a query where I get count totals using withCount().

```
$applications = Application::with('company')->withCount([
            'task', 
            'task as task_updated_count' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('task_status', '!=', 1);

        }])->get();
```

In my view I can loop through and display the results.

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Applications</th>
            <th class="text-center">Tasks</th>
            <th class="text-center">Updated Tasks</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        @foreach ($applications as $application)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $application->company->company_acronym }}</td>
                <td>{{ $application->application_name }}</td>
                <td class="text-center">{{ $application->task_count }}</td>
                <td class="text-center">{{ $application->task_updated_count }}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This will obviously give me a table listing the results with the $application->company->company_acronym listed for each $application.

What I'm trying to do list the applications by company "$application->company->company_acronym".

So the result would be:

Company 1 Acronym
    - AppName Count
    - AppName Count
    - AppName Count
Company 2 Acronym
    - AppName Count
    - AppName Count
    - AppName Count
Company 3 Acronym
    - AppName Count
    - AppName Count
    - AppName Count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupBy` function in collections to group by the acronym.

```
$applications = Application::with('company')->withCount([
    'task', 
    'task as task_updated_count' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('task_status', '!=', 1);
    }])->get();

$applicationGroups = $applications->groupBy(function($application) {
    return $application->company->company_acronym;
});
```

Then you can iterate over the groups to get desired output.

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Applications</th>
            <th class="text-center">Tasks</th>
            <th class="text-center">Updated Tasks</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach ($applicationGroups as $group => $applications)
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">{{ $group }}</td>
            </tr>
            @foreach ($applications as $application)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $application->application_name }}</td>
                    <td class="text-center">{{ $application->task_count }}</td>
                    <td class="text-center">{{ $application->task_updated_count }}</td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Perfect! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please Check Following Code

```
$applications = Application::with('company')->with([
            'task'  => function ($query) {
        $query->where('task_status', '!=', 1)->count();

    }, 
        'task_updated_count' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('task_status', '!=', 1)->count();

    }])->get();
```

Comment: My query works fine. It gives me the task count and the task_updated_count. I'm looking to display the results by company. This query gives me an Call to undefined relationship [task_updated_count] error.